# sql query with calculation from subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have two tables (well I have more but I simplify it some for this question)

**Invoice**

invoiceID        10

invoiceNo        1234

invoiceAmount    1000

invoiceStatus    2

**Payments**

paymentID        3

invoiceID        10

paymentAmount    500

paymentMethod    3

Now I need a query that gives me some values from table Invoice but also a calculation based on values from Payments for a certain invoiceID. What I would like to get is:

```
Invoice number, invoice amount and remaining amount to pay
--------------  ---------------    -----------------------
1234            1000               500
```

Can you help me finish up the query with a subquery that actually works.

```
select i.invoiceNo as 'Invoice Number', i.invoiceAmount as 'Invoice amount' (i.invoiceAmount - totallyPayed) as reminingToPay
from Invoice i
left join Payments p on (p.invoiceID = i.invoiceID)
where 
i.invoiceStatus = 2 
and totallyPayed = (select sum(p.PaymentAmount) from Payments where p.paymentMethod in (1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
SELECT i.invoiceNo AS 'Invoice Number',
       i.invoiceAmount AS 'Invoice amount',
      (i.invoiceAmount - COALESCE(p.totalPayed,0)) AS remainingToPay
FROM Invoice i
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT invoiceID,
         SUM(paymentAmount) AS totalPayed
  FROM payments
  WHERE paymentMethod IN (1, 2, 3)
  GROUP BY invoiceId
  ) p
  ON p.invoiceID = i.invoiceID
WHERE i.invoiceStatus = 2
```

First you get the sum of paymentAmount from payments table for each invoiceID and then you join with your invoice table to get the remainingToPay.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot Filipe.